# Select2 multiple parent not changing height on line-wrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-select2

Edit: It was caused by an obscure `height: 34px !important;` made by someone a long time - never trust old code. Commented and worked perfectly. Thanks Calvin Nunes for suggesting a snippet inclusion and Tayyab Khan for bringing the height issue that made me think about it. When trying to reproduce the behavior I thought about <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>-ing the old css file. I wasn't able to find it on code inspection, though... Sorry for the inconvenience.

Here where I work we use ASP.NET MVC 5, Bootstrap (v3.3.7), jQuery (v2.2.3) and we use the Select2 plugin (v4.0.5). The problem is, when I use `<select multiple><!--options--></select>` and select options enough to make it break a linke, the height does increase, but the parent doesn't follow, making it overlap the next line. Any idea of what's causing this and/or how to fix it?
This is what happens:

Before breaking line:
[image: Before breaking line]

After breaking line:
[image]

I looked up on select2 examples and cannot see a difference on implementation, and there it works perfectly... I opened code inspection on both to look for any relevant difference and couldn't find. Maybe I'm missing something.

Markup is this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <select id="contatos" class="form-control" multiple></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the script goes like this:

```
$('#contatos').select2({
    tags: true,
    tokenSeparators: [',', ' ', ';'],
    dataMiminumInputLength: 2,
    ajax: {
        url: '/Gerenciamento/Usuario/PesquisarUsuarios/',
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                termo: params.term
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
            var results = [];
            $(data).each(function (i, el) {
                results.push({
                    id: el.desEmail,
                    text: el.desNome + ' | ' + el.desEmail,
                    codUsuario: el.codUsuario,
                    desEmail: el.desEmail
                });
            });
            return { results: results }
        },
        delay: 400
    }
});
```

Note: This happens on all uses of select multiple in this application.

Comment: Please, post a snippet here, so we can reproduce the code and the problem and then try to find a fix for you

Comment: I'm making a snippet but simplifying the code doesn't reproduce the error... I believe this is a sign for a problem in some other css altering the default select2 behaviour. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns ou it was a CSS issue... Someone once thought it would be a good idea to use `.select2-container, .select2-selection--single { height: 34px !important; }`. Two problems: `important!` and `height`. If `min-height` was used, this problem wouldn't happen, but the `!important` is unforgivable. Thanks and sorry!

Answer (score 1):

It's css issue have you added select2-bootstrap.css in your page? check it because select2 css is given in it for bootstrap you can check height on line 10. It should be auto

```
.form-control.select2-container {
    height: auto !important;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: I haven't added select2-bootstrap.css, we are using it raw and the styling comes from bootstrap... I'm fiddling with css to find an answer.

Comment: But if you inspect your select2 element you will note it's adding class "select2-container" if it's adding then you should make height as auto in this class I think it will work